# Selecting users id based on affiliation to group

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database, where there are `groups` that have many `users` (1:N). Those two tables are designed to have a unique ID for every group and unique ID for every user. But now I came to a problem that I need to SELECT an ID of a group and also an ID of a user within that group (which is different from his real database ID). Is there some way to SELECT these sub-IDs in MySQL without actually changing users table structure?

What my current table structure looks like:

```
-----------------
| GROUPS        |
=================
| ID PK AUTO_INC|
| NAME          |
| DESCRIPTION   |
| ...other      |
| non-related   |
| columns       |
-----------------

------------------
| USERS          |
==================
| ID PK AUTO_INC |
| NAME           |
| GROUP          |
| AGE            | 
|...other        |
| non-related    |
| columns        |
------------------
```

**EDIT**: What I would like looks like this:

```
GROUPS
----------------------------------
| ID  | Name | Description | ... |
==================================
| 1   |  A   | First one   | ... |
| 2   |  B   | Second one  | ... |
| 3   |  C   | Third one   | ... |
----------------------------------
USERS
--------------------------------------
| ID  | Name    | Group  | Age | ... |
======================================
| 1   |  John   |   1    | 35  | ... |
| 2   |  Adam   |   1    | 22  | ... |
| 3   |  Bob    |   2    | 18  | ... |
| 4   |  Jane   |   1    | 38  | ... |
| 5   |  Emma   |   2    | 56  | ... |
| 6   |  Aaron  |   3    | 26  | ... |
| 7   |  Alice  |   2    | 48  | ... |
--------------------------------------

And as a result I would like to get:
-----------------------------------
| GID | UID| Name    |  Age | ... |
===================================
| 1   | 1  |  John   |  35  | ... |
| 1   | 2  |  Adam   |  22  | ... |
| 1   | 3  |  Jane   |  38  | ... |
| 2   | 1  |  Bob    |  18  | ... |
| 2   | 2  |  Emma   |  56  | ... |
| 2   | 3  |  Alice  |  48  | ... |
| 3   | 1  |  Aaron  |  26  | ... |
-----------------------------------
```

I hope now it will make sense.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If the tables contain some common fields, it simply looks like a JOIN query to me. Otherwise, hard to say anything without seeing the actual table structures.

Comment: What would the user id be based on?

Comment: I need them to be counted from 1.

Comment: I'll add table structure, but I don't think it would help much.

Comment: @HlavacekMichal In 'groups' table, NAME is the name of the group? How do you relate particular user with particular group?

Comment: @sashkello Yep, sure. And, each user has GROUP column, which is an ID of a group.

Comment: Ah, as I said, it looks like you simply need to JOIN on users.group = groups.id. I don't see a problem...

Comment: That would work if I needed a simple joined view of those two tables, and in that case, I wouldn't have asked this question at all. What I want to achieve here is select users of each group and give them an ID within that group (so, even if user has ID, I don't know, 12, how do I make SELECT to get a GROUP_ID and then his ID inside that group). I wouldn't like to use a particular key, so I'm trying to look for another solution.

Comment: @HlavacekMichal Please show a snippet from your two tables and sample desired output. It still looks like a join to me :)

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know how to do this is with variables

```
select
    t.id,
    t.name,
    t.group,
    t.rank as newid
from ( 
    select
        u.id,
        u.name,
        u.group,
        If(@group <> u.`Group`, @rownum := 1, @rownum := @rownum + 1) AS rank, 
        @group := u.`Group`
    from
        Users u 
            cross join (
            select
                @rownum := NULL,
                @group := 0
        ) as r 
    order by
        u.group,
        u.id
    ) as t
order by 
    t.group,
    t.id;
```

This method isn't guaranteed to work, but in practice it seems to.

**<kbd>[Example SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bfe00/11)</kbd>**

Comment: I'm sure that this query would work, but it's not exactly what I want. However, I can maybe explain what I want on this example of yours. How can you get a column with an integer 3 if I use your SQL? I mean, I literally need to get their "renumbered" ID based on their assigned group.

Comment: I actually think my English isn't on such level to explain this any better. I hate myself a little for that right now.